# problems with connection to MYSQL in localhost

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php to connect to my database in the localhost for the first time.  I have set the username to root and password is XXXX.  However, I am unable to connect; I get this error:

> Warning: mysqli::real_connect() [mysqli.real-connect]: (28000/1045):
>   Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
>   /home/as1609/public_html/ParseBanksPhase1/db.php on line 19 Connect
>   Error (1045) Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)

The php file I am using to connect to my database shown below.  Any ideas on what could be wrong?

```
<?php

$MYSQL_CONFIG=array(
    'host'=>'localhost',
    'user'=>'root',
    'password'=>'XXXX',
    'db'=>'csv_parse',
    'encoding'=>'utf8',
);

$mysqli = mysqli_init();
if (!$mysqli) {
    die('mysqli_init failed');
}

if (!$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET NAMES ' . $MYSQL_CONFIG['encoding'])) {
    die('Setting MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND failed');
}

if (!$mysqli->real_connect($MYSQL_CONFIG['host'], $MYSQL_CONFIG['user'], $MYSQL_CONFIG['password'], $MYSQL_CONFIG['db'])) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: It seems you did not change your host's default password. Try by using password as blank (eg,) 'password'=>'',

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have that problem due to Permission, Can you tell me what Software your using for Database instfruscture? (MySQL, phpmyadmin, SQL Server etc)

I recommend using [PDO MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) Login format, is more secure then Mysqli Connect.

**Here is example of your code would look like**: 
Setting up Array:

```
$MYSQL_CONFIG = array(
    'host'=>'localhost',
    'user'=>'root',
    'password'=>'XXXX',
    'db'=>'csv_parse',
    'encoding'=>'utf8',
);
```

**Connect through PDO with Error Management:**

```
try {
        $Establishment = new PDO("mysql:host=$MYSQL_CONFIG['host'];dbname=$MYSQL_CONFIG['db']", $MYSQL_CONFIG['user'], $MYSQL_CONFIG['password']);
        $Establishment->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $MySQLerror) {
            echo "Connection failed: " . $MYSQLerror->getMessage();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your php is not allowing localhost connections.
I don't know on what OS u are, but google "Enable root acces mysql". Here is a linux example http://benrobb.com/2007/01/15/howto-remote-root-access-to-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

User `'root'@'localhost'` doesn't have privileges on database `csv_parse`.
You can add all privileges to user with:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON csv_parse.* to 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'XXXX';
```

If you don't want add all privileges you can list privileges which user should have on database: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Comment: Tried this but still getting same error message
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON csv_parse.* to 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'XXXX';